# How do I read data from a file using Python?

Tags: python, scripting

I am looking for a  lookup function for print corresponding names. I have a list file

```
a Chief manager
b Assistant general manager
c general manager
D CTO
E CEO
```

I have a variable “user” in my script
I want to check the variable in first column, if the value match then print corresponding name

> Eg   if “user”==a then print “Chief manager”

Comment: You should read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a dictionary will be easier.

```
d = { 'a': 'Chief Manager', 'b': 'Assistant General Manager', 'c': 'General Manager', 'D': 'CTO', 'E': 'CEO' }
user = 'a'
print(d[user])
# Chief Manager
```

To load that file into a dictionary, you could do this:

```
with open('/path/to/my/file') as myFile:
    d = dict(line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in myFile)

print(d['a'])
# Cheif manager
```

---

If you want to parse a CSV file, it depends on how the file is actually formatted.  If it looked like this:

```
a,"Cheif manager"
b,"Assistant general manager"
c,"general manager"
D,"CTO"
E,"CEO"
```

You could read that in like this:

```
from csv import reader
d = dict(row for row in reader(open('/path/to/my/file'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))
print(d['a'])
# Cheif manager
```

Comment: That list is a file which frequently change.

Comment: @Albin: Well, basically you'll want to parse that file and put the contents into the dictionary.  It's not going to be much easier working with the raw text in the file.

Comment: @jeff Thanks. 
what about a csv file ?

Comment: @Albin: A CSV formatted file is just another file format.  It shouldn't be much different than if it was in the format that you have shown in your question.  Using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module can make parsing and creating the dictionary relatively easy.

Comment: @martineau: I agree, though Albin did ask about it so I was inclined to provide an example but without having to make up additional data.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: True, but he doesn't know any better. ;-)

Comment: @martineau, @Jeff Mercado I am doing some experiments with python.  Trying to create a mobile application to send rule based sms reply (automated).  Now working with data.csv file.
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Just uploaded that project to http://code.google.com/p/smsbot have a look and contribute

Comment: @Albin: I see you've applied what we've talked about here, nice.  :)

Comment: @Jeff Its just because of your help ... Now looking for a front end editor for the file data.csv

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the first column would be unique in someway, your first task would be to construct a dictonary with keys from the first column and values from the second.

to construct the dictionary, try it in the following manner.

```
org_dict = dict()
line = 'a Chief manager'
key,value = line.split(None,1)
org_dict[key] = value
```

Now to get each line from your file, you can open the file and read then line by line.

```
with open('myfile') as f:
    for line in f:
        # process your line
```

Comment: Try `fields = line.split(None, 1)` to split the line into the letter and the complete name.